# On-board monocular odometry for quadcopter stabilization

Tags: quadcopter, odometry, stability

Has anyone done this with EKF/PID on a small microcontroller? Or know of code snippets to help implementing this?

Comment: you mean this: https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo?